# SQLCriterion ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, queryover

What is the correct syntax to create a SQLCriterion?

I have the following code:

```
var sqlCriterion = new SQLCriterion(
                new SqlString("{alias}.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.fGetSomeIds(?1, ?2))"),
                new object[] { "param1", "param2" },
                new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String, NHibernateUtil.String });

query.Where(sqlCriterion);
```

where query is my QueryOver-instance (created with NHibernateSession)

When I call query.List() I get the following exception:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index
```

which is thrown somewhere in NHibernate.Criterion.SQLCriterion.ToSqlString(..)

Is the syntax of my SQLCriterion-constructor wrong or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This adjustment should make it:

```
var criterion = NHibernate.Criterion.Expression
    .Sql("({alias}.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.fGetSomeIds(?, ?))"
        + " AS MyCriteria",
        new object[] { "param1", "param2" },
        new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String, NHibernateUtil.String });

// query.Where(sqlCriterion);
query.Where(criterion);
```

Comment: Great to see that Philipp. It is not so easy get into the NHibernate... but the profit later... is awesome. Good luck

Comment: I agree as I have already worked alot with NHibernate. However this is my first time working with QueryOver as I try to convert a big amount of old inline sql search logic to NH. For the most part I think QueryOver is pretty easy to use, it´s just those few special cases which take some time to understand.