# CreateCriteria Contains Restriction

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I am using Criteria API for querying and want to query on a column that contains Full Text index.

But then in Criteria API I have not been able to successfully find `CONTAINS`.

Is there a way to use `CONTAINS` in Criteria? I used `CreateQuery` and was able to get it working but wanted to know if there is a way to get it done using `CreateCriteria`.

Any pointers towards the same is highly appreciated as I have been searching for this from quite some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can generate custom SQL parts, with **`Criterion.Expresssion.Sql`**. (There is an [example how to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26142155))

This could be the way in our case

```
var searchedValue = "searched value";

var session = ... // get session 

// dynamic way to construct some SQL part
var criterion = NHibernate.Criterion.Expression
    .Sql(" CONTAINS ({alias}.LastName, ? ) ",
        new object[] { searchedValue},
        new IType[] { NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String});

// our criteria
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<MyEntity>();

// with our FULLTEXT filter
criteria.Add(criterion);

// result..
var list = criteria
    .SetFirstResult(0) // paging
    .SetMaxResults(10)
    .List<MyEntity>();
```

Comment: One more question. I tried applying a filter on a one-to-one mapping. What I am trying to achieve is to add a where clause when pulling the object. I added a `property-ref` and that just pulled based on that reference but I want another condition to be added.

Is that possible ? I do not want to use a bag, because `property-ref` + my condition will give me one unique object.

Comment: That is different topic. I'd suggest.. accept this answer to your question.. and raise new one. You surely (with enough details provided) get your answer

Comment: The {alias} will be the alias Hibernate sets on the base model that I would be using to query right ?